# Django comment(s) on users in database

Tags: django

I'm currently building a Django website where staff has control over users, and, within those powers, I'd like to add one where the staff members can add private comments on users so that they can be read by whoever has the power to do so.

So I started building the user `models.py` here what I did:

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comments = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My question: how can I add a comment field every time a staff member wants to? Like, with the above code, I can only have one comment per user.

Everything is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

**1. ForeignKey**

Make a separate model for the comments and have a ForeignKey to the `User` model. That way, multiple comments can be linked to the same user.

**2. `ArrayField`**

If you're using Postgres database, you can use the [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

Cons: Editing in the admin panel is not very user friendly.

**3. `JSONField`**

You can also keep multiple comments in a JSON array.

Cons: Editing in the admin panel is not user friendly.

---

P.S.: If you decide to use either `ArrayField` or `JSONField`, check out an app I've made called [`django-jsonform`](https://github.com/bhch/django-jsonform). This will make editing JSON and `ArrayField` nice and user-friendly.